# ArraList.forEach for Java is not working properly within a while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I am implementing the breadth first search for an undirected graph using Java. However only one vertex get processed. Adjoining nodes for other vertices are returned as 0, even though they are properly added.

```
public class Graph {
   class Vertex {
        String label;
        ArrayList<Vertex> adjNodeList;
        boolean isVisited;

        public Vertex(String label) {
            this.label = label;
            this.adjNodeList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.isVisited = false;
        }
   }

   ArrayList<Vertex> vertices;

   public Graph() {
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<>();    
   }

   public void addNode(String label) {
       this.vertices.add(new Vertex(label));
   }

   public void addEdge(String start, String end) {
       this.vertices.forEach((e) -> {
           if(e.label.equalsIgnoreCase(start)) {
               e.adjNodeList.add(new Vertex(end));
           }
       });
   }

   public void printGraph() {
      this.vertices.forEach((e -> {
          System.out.print("Vertex - " + e.label + " -> ");
          e.adjNodeList.forEach((v -> {
              System.out.print(v.label);
          }));

          System.out.println();
      }));
   }

   public void breadthFirstSearch() {
        Queue<Vertex> theQueue = new LinkedList<>();

        Vertex rv = this.vertices.get(0);
        rv.isVisited = true;
        theQueue.add(rv);

        while(!theQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex vertex = theQueue.remove();
            System.out.println("Processing - " + vertex.label);
            System.out.println("List size - " + vertex.adjNodeList.size());

            vertex.adjNodeList.forEach((e) -> {
                if(!e.isVisited) {
                    e.isVisited = true;
                    theQueue.add(e);
                    System.out.println("Enqueued - " + e.label);
                }
            });
        }
   }
```

When graph is printed it shows all the edges correctly, but the BFS method can only process A and it's edges as seen below...

```
Vertex - A -> BC
Vertex - B -> G
Vertex - C -> D
Vertex - D -> E
Vertex - E -> 
Vertex - G -> 
Processing - A
List size - 2
Enqueued - B
Enqueued - C
Processing - B
List size - 0
Processing - C
List size - 0
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even though they are properly added.

I assume by this that when you call addEdge - eg, by `addEdge("A", "B");` - we can assume that you have already called `addNode("A")` and `addNode("B")`.

If so, then the problem is in your `addEdge` method :

```
public void addEdge(String start, String end) {
   this.vertices.forEach((e) -> {
       if(e.label.equalsIgnoreCase(start)) {
           e.adjNodeList.add(new Vertex(end));
       }
   });
```

}

So given `addEdge("A", "B");`, this code finds your already-added start vertex "A" - but then creates a `new Vertex` "B" WITHOUT looking for any that may have already been added.  That new vertex has an empty adjNodeList, which will remain empty.

In other words, the Vertex "B" being referenced from "A" is a different instance from the Vertex "B" that is in the `this.vertices`.

So you should change `addEdge` (and, to do a sure job, `addNode` as well) to first look in `this.vertices` for an existing vertex.

eg something like this:

```
 public Vertex fetchNode(String label) {
   return this.vertices.stream()
              .filter(v -> v.getLabel().equals(label))
              .findAny()
              .orElseGet( () -> {
                  Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(label));
                  this.vertices.add(newVertex);
                  return newVertex;
               });
  }

  public void addEdge(String start, String end) {
     this.vertices.forEach((e) -> {
         if(e.label.equalsIgnoreCase(start)) {
             e.adjNodeList.add(fetchNode(end));
         }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Super ! That was the issue. Thanks